# Does coownership of a bank account have tax implications?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I have "Power of Attorney" (POA) on a bank account in the United States owned by my father. I am also a US citizen and resident and pay income tax in this domain.

If I became a co-owner on this bank account would it have any tax implications for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are joint tenant on a bank account, then any interest payable to the account is income to you.  If you simply have power of attorney, then that is generally not income to you.  This is usually only a very modest amount of interest income, if indeed there's any at all.

Simply having a bank account is not itself a taxable event.

Note that if you have any tax disputes or collections, the account may be subject to a lien or seizure.  If you are hit with an examination or audit, then the account may be investigated for deposits and withdrawals to construct your income and expenses.

Comment: The last paragraph is the most important one. People are often not aware that becoming co-owners with someone else exposes them to that someone else's debtors.